# SQL summing with difference

Tags: sql

The SQL Server query I have is:

```
SELECT
  ep.employeeID, ep.punchdate, rc.creditAmount
FROM
  EmployeePunch ep 
    INNER JOIN
      ResponderCredit rc ON rc.employeeID = ep.employeeID AND 
      rc.punchdate = rc.creditdate
ORDER BY ep.employeeID
```

and get a result set:

```
EmployeeID      Date             CreditAmount
-----------    -------          -------------- 
  5             01/01/2007              5
  5             03/01/2007              7
  5             04/22/2007              15
  6             01/01/2007              3
  6             01/12/2007              4
```

And I want to group by EmployeeID and Credit amount.  The catch is that I need the change in the Credit Amount between the max and min date so:

```
EmployeeID          CreditAmount
-----------         --------------
  5                          10
  6                          1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit the data so that 15 goes to 03/01 and 7 goes to 4/22. It's confusing for now.

Comment: Data needs to include the boundary conditions: if 3/1 amount is 15 and 4/22 amount is 12, I should have a result of 7 instead of 10?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle:

```
SELECT  r1.employeeID, amMax - amMin
FROM    (
    SELECT employeeID, amMin
    FROM  (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ep.EmployeeID ORDER BY rc.creditdate) AS rnMin,
            ep.employeeID, rc.creditAmount AS amMin
        FROM
            EmployeePunch ep, ResponderCredit rc
        WHERE
            rc.employeeID = ep.employeeID
            AND rc.punchdate = rc.creditdate
        )
    WHERE rn_min = 1
    ) r1,
    (
    SELECT employeeID, amMin
    FROM  (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ep.EmployeeID ORDER BY rc.creditdate DESC) AS rnMax,
            ep.employeeID, rc.creditAmount AS amMax
        FROM
            EmployeePunch ep, ResponderCredit rc
        WHERE
            rc.employeeID = ep.employeeID
            AND rc.punchdate = rc.creditdate
        )
    WHERE rn_max = 1
    ) r2
WHERE   r1.employeeID = r2.employeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

for MS SQL, this should do it

```
SELECT
  ep.employeeID, rc.creditAmount, 
  datediff(month, max(ep.punchdate), min(ep.punchdate))
FROM
  EmployeePunch ep 
INNER JOIN
  ResponderCredit rc ON rc.employeeID = ep.employeeID AND 
    rc.punchdate = rc.creditdate 
group by
  EmployeeID, Credit
ORDER BY
  ep.employeeID
```

Comment: I think the OP is actually looking for the difference between the min rc.creditAmount and the max rc.creditAmount.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's almost certainly a typo on the part of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for MSSQL.

It will show a negative value if the credit has gone down over the time period.

It's got a few inner joins and can probably be optimized, but probably not by much

```
SELECT maxCredit.employeeID, maxCredit.creditAmount - minCredit.creditAmount
FROM
(
SELECT
    ep.employeeID, rc.creditAmount
FROM
    EmployeePunch ep 
INNER JOIN
    ResponderCredit rc
ON rc.employeeID = ep.employeeID AND rc.punchdate = rc.creditdate
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT ep2.employeeID, MAX(ep2.punchdate) AS maxCreditdate
    FROM EmployeePunch ep2 GROUP BY ep2.employeeID
    ) innermax 
ON innermax.employeeID = ep.employeeID AND ep.punchdate = innermax.maxcreditDate
) maxCredit
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT
    ep.employeeID, rc.creditAmount
FROM
    EmployeePunch ep 
INNER JOIN
    ResponderCredit rc
ON rc.employeeID = ep.employeeID AND rc.punchdate = rc.creditdate
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT ep3.employeeID, MIN(ep3.punchdate) AS minCreditdate
    FROM EmployeePunch ep3 GROUP BY ep3.employeeID
    ) innermin
ON innermin.employeeID = ep.employeeID AND ep.punchdate = innermin.mincreditDate
) minCredit
ON maxCredit.employeeID = minCredit.employeeID
```

Comment: I was just doing it as per the result required

Comment: The result required is confusing as the min and max credit amounts for each employee are also the min and max dates.  I've got it right this time though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for I believe....

```
SELECT
  ep.employeeID, Max(datediff(day, ep.punchdate, rc.creditDate)) As [# of Days], rc.creditAmount
FROM
  EmployeePunch ep 
INNER JOIN
  ResponderCredit rc 
ON 
    rc.employeeID = ep.employeeID AND rc.punchdate = rc.creditdate
group by ep.employeeID, rc.creditAmount
ORDER BY ep.employeeID
```

Will yield results:

```
EmployeeID    # of Days    CreditAmount    
5                 0             5    
5                 2             7    
5                 111           15    
6                 0             3    
6                 334           4
```